# GCP Connecting to SQL for a Cloud Run Anthos nodejs service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

Trying connect SQL instance to Cloud Run Service, using Fully Managed cloud run works fine but when I try to connect service via Anthos (which is required as we need to use websockets on services) I just get ENOENT (No Entry), update IAM for GKE with correct permissions, recreated cluster with all services enabled/

Here's the deploy command I am doing

```
    gcloud run deploy \
    --project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID} \
    --platform gke \
    --cluster dev \
    --cluster-location ${GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE} \
    --image gcr.io/${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}/${PROJECT_NAME} \
    --set-cloudsql-instances "${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}:europe-west1:dev" \
    --set-env-vars "$(tr '\n' ',' < "${ENV_KEY_PRODUCTION}")" \
    --set-env-vars "SERVICE=${1}" \
    --set-env-vars "DB_HOST=/cloudsql/${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}:europe-west1:dev" \
    "${1}"
```

If I use the private IP from SQL and remove `--set-cloudsql-instances` and set DB_HOST as private IP it works.

But adding `--set-cloudsql-instances` should make a sidecar for service in GKE cluster and allow it to connect to SQL?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation isn't clear... the parameter ['--set-cloudsql-instances' is only available for Cloud Run Managed version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy#--set-cloudsql-instances). The first sentence of the section is important. And the limitation is not clear in the doc

> Only applicable if connecting to Cloud Run (fully managed). Specify --platform=managed to use:

> --[no-]allow-unauthenticated
> Whether to enable allowing unauthenticated access to the service. This may take a few moments to take effect. Use --allow-unauthenticated to enable and --no-allow-unauthenticated to disable.

> --clear-vpc-connector
> Remove the VPC connector for this Service.

> --revision-suffix=REVISION_SUFFIX
> Specify the suffix of the revision name. Revision names always start with the service name automatically. For example, specifying [--revision-suffix=v1] for a service named 'helloworld', would lead to a revision named 'helloworld-v1'.

> --vpc-connector=VPC_CONNECTOR
> Set a VPC connector for this Service.
> These flags modify the Cloud SQL instances this Service connects to. You can specify a name of a Cloud SQL instance if it's in the same project and region as your Cloud Run service; otherwise specify :: for the instance. At most one of these may be specified:

> --add-cloudsql-instances=[CLOUDSQL-INSTANCES,…]
> Append the given values to the current Cloud SQL instances.

> --clear-cloudsql-instances
> Empty the current Cloud SQL instances.

> --remove-cloudsql-instances=[CLOUDSQL-INSTANCES,…]
> Remove the given values from the current Cloud SQL instances.

> --set-cloudsql-instances=[CLOUDSQL-INSTANCES,…]
> Completely replace the current Cloud SQL instances with the given values.

Comment: Just adding to the answer, you may want to have a look at the supported methods to connect from GKE to Cloud SQL. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine?_ga=2.56439275.-1952980062.1584577065#proxy-with-service-account-key

Comment: @AntonioRamirez, K8S pod aren't exactly the same thing as Cloud Run deployment! You can run multiple container with Knative, only one, and thus, you can't achieve this!